# Rails :dependent => :destroy in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in project.rb:

```
has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
```

And in item.rb:

```
belongs_to :project
```

My projects fixture:

```
b1_s_first_project:
  title: B1's first project
```

And my items fixture:

```
b1_s_first_project_s_first_item:
  title: B1's first project's first item
  project: b1_s_first_project
```

In my unit test, I set local variables `item = items(:b1_s_first_project_s_first_item)` and `project = projects(:b1_s_first_project)`. When I call `project.destroy`, `project.destroyed?` returns true, but `item.destroyed?` returns nil, as if it hadn't been destroyed. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you might need to add `item.reload` before testing if it's destroyed or not

Comment: Very good. Essentially correct. `item.reload` raised the Object not found exception, so I just changed the assertion to `assert !Item.exists?(item)`. Funny though, I thought the whole point of the ActiveRecord was to update the objects automatically so you wouldn't have to re-find each time. It seems as though the .destroyed? flag would be one of the things that would update itself.

Comment: @steven: The thing is once the object is loaded it's cached somehow and then there is now broadcast process to let the object know that it's deleted ^^ Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative method by leveraging `.reload` on the association record using the assertion `assert_raise`. This works under Rails 5, but should work in the the previous two versions.

Model set-up:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy
end

# bar.rb
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :foo
end
```

Fixture set-up:

```
# foos.yml
oof:
    title: Hello

# bars.yml
rab:
    title: World!
    foo: oof
```

Model minitest:

```
test 'foo should destroy dependency bar on destroy' do
    foo, bar = foos(:off), bars(:rab)

    assert foo.destroy
    assert_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) { bar.reload }
end
```